# Worded Problem: Model a Plane Landing

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]

I have no idea to model this. All I know are the two points $(50, 10)$ and $(0,0)$
Then from after solving I get $a=1/12500$ and $b=0$

The textbook answers are:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the word "smoothly" so this means that the plane should start the landing with zero-derivative (no slope) along the $x$ coordinate in its trajectory, so $y'(x)=0$ when $x = 50 \, km$.

Take this into account and notice that $y(0) = 0$  is always satisfied, no matter what the values of $a$ and $b$ are. Plug this information to your problem ($y(50)=10, \ y'(50) = 0$) and you will have:

$$a = -\frac{1}{6250} \wedge b = 75,$$

when $x$ is measured in $km$.

Cheers!

Comment: you can use a derivative equation to solve for a & b?

... really...

Comment: Hi there again. Yes, indeed you can, but notice that if you compute the first derivative and evaluate it in some fixed $x$ position, say $x^*$, then $y'(x^*) = y'(x^*;a,b)$ is then a function of $a$ and $b$, exclusively (likewise for $y(x^*;a,b)$).

Comment: i see... cool, ill be sure to think of this for future questions. 

Thank you! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!